# Data validation with vba

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Normally it is possible to apply data validation in excel through vba but i am having a specific problem

I am using the indirect method for applying validation,normally when i dont use vba i get a warning by excel that "source currently evaluates to an error,do u want to continue?" (this is because cells which indirect refers to may be empty), now i can easily skip this error in excel by clicking "Yes"

Here's the link http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html (Dependent validation lists)

But when i try to perform the same thing using vba i am getting a runtime error,there is no friendly prompt which allows me to continue.How can i handle this kind of error.

On error resume isnt working because then vba doesnt apply validation at all.

Here's the code

```
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input").Range("AB11:AB65536")
With rng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=INDIRECT(cablecode&""_depth_""&$Q11&""_""&$Z11&""_values"")"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

cablecode is a static named range

Q11 and Z11 refer to inputs in that particular row

*depth* and *values* are normal strings

cablecode can have two values = "is" or "iec"

Q11 can be "xlpe" or "pvc"

Z11 can be "al" or "cu"

since cablecode is constant for whole project ive referred to it directly,
Q11 and Z11 can be different for different rows so ive referred to them seperately

The whole string comes out to be
"is_depth_al_xlpe_values"
similarly different permuations,and all named ranges are already defined

Comment: This will be more clear if you can kindly post the source code.

Comment: @EdwinBautista ive added the source code

Comment: What is the error and what line is the error on?

Comment: The error is occurring when vba tries to add validation..i am getting a runtime error '1004' "application defined or object defined error'..its due to the fact that validation will currently evaluate to an error and vba wont let me continues...whereas excel does..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the following line needs correction from

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=INDIRECT(cablecode&""_depth_""&$Q11&""_""&$Z11&""_values"")"
```

to

```
dim cellToBeReferred as string
cellToBeReferred = cablecode & "_depth_" & Range("$Q11").Value & "_" _
& Range("$Q11").Value & "_values"

.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=INDIRECT(" & cellToBeReferred  & ")"
```

Taking the string out will help you debug the issue and figure what is the value of named range, you'd want to refer to. See what value `cellToBeReferred` results into and correct the concatenation using above.

**EDIT after reading OPs comment**

In that case, surround the `INDIRECT` with `ISERROR` and give a dummy cell reference.
For e.g.

```
"=IFERROR(INDIRECT(" & cellToBeReferred  & "), Z1)"
```

Where Z1 is a cell to be referred if `INDIRECT` fails.

Comment: i know what the error is..its simply when Q11 and Z11 are not specified the string would become is_depth_(nothing here)_(nothing here)_values...since it is not a named range it gives an error..the problem is excel would let me continue because later i can input Q11 and Z11 and the validation will be available..but vba wont let me continue...

Comment: but in case of dummy cell reference the original validation wont be there..and if a user enters data in Z11 and Q11 he wont get the list he was supposed to

Comment: If the named range is proper & has data, it will be referred. In case of error, Z1 (which is a temporary reference) will be referred.

Comment: its still not working...its not catching that specific warning that excel shows in case indirect is currently pointing to error..(and yes i used "ISERROR")

Comment: Well i got it after getting your hint as "ISERROR",the thing is it still wont catch with the "ISERROR" statement because named ranges which consist of more than one cell return "#value" error if you use them on a cell.Instead i used "ISREF"
Here's the better format
"=IF(ISREF(INDIRECT(cablecode&""_temp_""&$Q11&""_""&$Z11&""_values"")),INDIRECT    (cablecode&""_temp_""&$Q11&""_""&$Z11&""_values""),NA)"

Answer (score 0):

No way to suppress warning in VBA. Temporarily assign a value to the reference cell and clear it later. This will prevent the run-time error that's avoided by the UI when selecting "Yes" to "The source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue" dialog box.

ex.

```
thisworkbook.range("Q11").value = "1"

'data validation - i.e. Formula1:="=INDIRECT(Q11)"

thisworkbook.range("Q11").value = ""
```